# Sqlite database and app upgrade process doubts

Tags: ios, sqlite

We have stored our app sqlite database in the Library folder. We need that for future app upgrades from app store, the database included in the upgraded app to delete the database from the installed one when users download it from app store. We have checked from different sources, and they say that only the content in Documents folder will not be deleted.

Please can you confirm this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Library folder will survive an app upgrade. It's possible that Library/Caches will be deleted but not Library in general.

The simplest solution is to have the new version of your app use a different filename for the database file and have code that looks for and deletes the old database file.